# In function overridding why we not declare it static

Tags: php, overriding, static-functions

I have a child class where I define a static function:

```
class functionover
{
    function override($num1, $num2)
    {
        $total = $num1+$num2;
    }


}
class childfunctionover extends functionover
{
    static function override($num1, $num2)
    {
        $sum = $num1+$num2;
    }
}



functionover :: override(10, 20);
```

When I run my program it shows error:

`Cannot make non static method functionover::override() static in class childfunctionover`

How come?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

PHP is kinda strict when we talk about inheritance, extending and overriding methods (those are not functions! Do not get fooled by `function` keyword.).

If parent has `static` method, then your override can **only** be `static`. You cannot turn `static` into `non-static`.

This works both ways. You cannot override `non-static` method to be `static` one. This would violate many inheritance rules.

When you override methods, the rules are as follows:

1. Child's method name must be exactly the same as parent's method name
2. Child's method must accept the same number of arguments. If some default values are defined, they must be the same
3. Type of method's calling (`static` or not) must be preserved.

Those can be not the all rules that apply. For more information go to [Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php)

### Solution

Either change parent's method to be `static` or remove `static` keyword from child's method.